# Reading value from memory location (with 24-bit address) in 8-bit microcontroller

Tags: c, pointers, memory, embedded

I thought it should be as simple as:

```
uint32_t getCrc(void)
{
    uint32_t expectedCrc = *(uint32_t*)0x27FF0;

    return expectedCrc;
}
```

And if the memory location has the following value:[image: the following value]

Then the `expectedCrc` should equal to `0xECD8743D`

But surprisingly, the value is: `0x82828282`

I tried defining a pointer to `uint32_t` and assign the memory address to it as following:

```
uint32_t getCrc(void)
{
    uint32_t *ptr = (uint32_t*)0x27FF0;

    uint32_t expectedCrc = *ptr;

    return expectedCrc;
}
```

But the value of the pointer itself was `0xFFFF` and `expectedCrc` equal `0x82828282`

I found these two values in a different memory address:

[image]

I also tried the same with `char *ptr = (char*)0x27FF0` but it gave the same values.

Finally, I tried to check what is the size of a pointer to char in this controller using `uint8_t size = sizeof(char*);` and the answer was `0xb0` which equals `176`.

I think it has something to do with the 24-bit memory address and the CPU architecture. I'm working on `stm8` controller.

Could someone explain why does this happen?

**UPDATE**

I tried replacing the address `0x27FF0` with `0xFFF0` and it worked fine. So the problem is with the long address. I want to write the CRC value in the last address to avoid over-writing it with the code itself in case the program went bigger. How can I handle this?

Comment: It looks, like the environment supports only 16-bit integers. Is there no compiler warning with `-Wall`? Does `uint32_t *ptr = (uint32_t*)0x27FF0LLU` make any difference?

Comment: As you access flash you should add volatile keyword `uint32_t expectedCrc = *(volatile uint32_t*)0x27FF0;` But i'm not sure this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I tried option `-Wall` but it is unknown. I'm using `Cosmic`. But I enabled warnings and there was none regarding this function. I tried `LLU` and it showed `bad integer constant` and with only `U` it compiled but made no difference. I also tried `volatile` but with not difference.

Comment: What architecture?  Many compilers for 8 bit micros require special handling for pointers to suit different addressing modes and capabilities (they have variable width pointers).  I am assuming STM8 given you other question, but it really is relevant to the question and needs to be stated. Like your other question, the answer is in the manual (`@far` pointers) and in an understanding of the architecture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Cosmic compiler datasheet https://www.cosmic-software.com/pdf/cxstm8_pd.pdf

> cxstm8 provides 2 different memory models depending on the size of the application.
>
> For applications smaller that 64k, the “section 0” memory model provides the best code density by defaulting function calls and pointers to 2 bytes.
>
> For applications bigger than 64k, the standard memory model provides the best flexibility for using easily the linear addressing space. Each model comes with its own set of libraries.

This may be the cause for your problem. If you want to access the memory location of above 16 bit address directly you need to use the correct memory model.

Answer (score 2):

As @Raje answered that it is about the memory models, I did further reading in the **COSMIC user's guide** and I found the following:

> The STM8 compiler supports two memory models for application
>   larger than 64K, allowing you to choose the most efficient behavior
>   depending on your processor configuration and your application. All
>   these models allow the code to be larger than 64K and then function
>   pointers are defaulted to @far pointers (3 bytes). Data pointers are
>   defaulted to @near pointers (2 bytes) unless explicitly declared with
>   the @far modifier.

Therefore, the solution was to add `@far` to the pointer's type as following:

```
uint32_t calculatedCrc = 0;

expectedCrc = *(@far uint32_t*)0x27FF0;
```

This got the problem solved.